# Postgres: Inserting rows into table with foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a foreign key `type` which links to table `wp_types`.  Whenever I try and insert a row into that table I get the error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for schema base
LINE 1: SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "base"."wp_types" x WHERE "id" OPERATOR(p...
                       ^
QUERY:  SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "base"."wp_types" x WHERE "id" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR SHARE OF x
```

The query is being executed as postgres.
Also I do not understand what this query is trying to do, it is clearly linked with checking the foreign key constraints but I don't understand how.

Comment: What is the reason for using `ONLY` in your query?

Answer (score 2):

From postgresql docs:

> If ONLY is specified, only that table is scanned. If ONLY is not specified, the table and all its descendant tables (if any) are scanned.

As you mentioned error is connected with checking foreign keys. When ONLY is specified postgres can not check them and it may cause an error.

Comment: I get that.  What I don't understand is the permissions issue or how to work out what is wrong.  The both tables are owned by the user that is trying to do the insert and that user has ALL on all tables and sequences in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

1. Is it possible you dropped the superuser permissions from the postgres user?
2. What are the permissions for the base schema?

Now one thing to consider is that you aren't sure what the query is doing.  A simple `EXPLAIN` can show you what it is doing, but the error suggests the problem is with schema permissions, not with what the query is doing.

Try:

```
 GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA base TO postgres;
```